# How to center lines of text using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Illustrating a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{Short Name \\ Really long Name}
\chead{Title}
\rhead{Date}

\begin{document}
|
\end{document}
```

In my plain case I want the *Short Name* to be centred above the *Really long Name*

```
\lhead{\centering Short Name \\ Really long Name}
```

is not an option

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `tabular` in the head.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
Short Name \\ Really long Name
\end{tabular}}
\chead{Title}
\rhead{Date}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I suggest you to change the head height with `\setlength{\headheight}{25pt}`, for example.

[image]